# android - dialog with dynamic listview at top and container at bottom + AutoSize Dialog

Tags: android, listview, layout, dialog, size

Actually, I want a dialog showing a listview at top and a bottom menu bar...

I want the dialog to adjust it's size to the listview and bottom bar

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/llList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/illBottom"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
</ListView>

<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/illBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    android:paddingRight="4dip" >

    ...

</com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsLinearLayout>
```

Setting the listview to be above `illBottom` and the LinearLayout to no relative position, the listview is not showing up... Setting it the way I have, makes the Dialog always maximum size (wrap_content for the ListView does not work...)

Comment: why do you use a relative layout ?

Comment: Actually, because I want the bottom bar to always show up, no matter how big the listview is

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Build-in-List does it for you:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(....
```